# trigger jQuery event in React

Tags: jquery, reactjs

How do I fire this inside say an axios callback in a React app?

```
jQuery('body').trigger({
    type: 'action',
    event: 'submit',
    value: 'success'
});
```

EDIT:
Basically I need to call out of React into a legacy jQuery implementation, that expects the pub-sub pattern like the example above.

Answer (score 0):

Use keyboard events from React - http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html For example:

```
var CommentForm = React.createClass({
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    alert("YES again");
    return;
  },  
  handleKeyPress: function(e){console.log(e.which);if(e.which == 13){this.handleSubmit();}},
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="postCon">
          <form className="commentForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <textarea onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} className="textA input" placeholder="Your comment" ref="author" />
          </form>
        </div>
    );
  }
})
```

Comment: Added some more details, maybe it is now clear what I need to do.

Comment: if you think this answer helps you mark this as a right answer, so that other can be beniitted :)